# Is there a disaster recovery procedure or plan for Azure DevOps code repository?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, repository, corruption, disaster-recovery

We are looking for a disaster recovery plan or procedure for the Azure DevOps code repository in case of any emergency. 
If there is any request or ticket process? 
What is the procedure we need to follow in case our system goes down or code gets corrupted?

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? Can Mohit's answer below helps to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Most deletion operations in Azure DevOps are recoverable. So the `**feature**`: Disaster Recovery is not a capability  on the product roadmap.

You can find the discussion here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/838587/disaster-recovery-for-azure-devops.html

While the code is perfectly safe on Azure infrastructure, there are cases where a centralized local backup of all projects and repositories is needed. These might include Corporate Policies, Disaster Recovery and Business Continuity Plans.

You can refer below github sample for achieving the similar result if you are looking to download repo for your reference:

https://github.com/beralves/azure-devops-backup

Alternatively , You can help protect your deployment from data loss by creating a regular schedule of backups for the databases that Azure DevOps Server depends on.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/backup-db-architecture?view=azure-devops

Hope it helps.